# What's the denominator for ElasticSearch scores?

Tags: lucene, elasticsearch, bonsai-elasticsearch

I have a search which has multiple criterion.

Each criterion (grouped by `should`) has a different weighted score.

ElasticSearch returns a list of results; each with a score - which seems an arbitrary score to me. This is because I can't find a denominator for that score.

My question is - how can I represent each score as a ratio?

Dividing each score by `max_score` would not work since it'll show the best match as a 100% match with the search criteria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `_score` calculation depends on the combination of queries used.  For instance, a simple query like:

```
{ "match": { "title": "search" }}
```

would use Lucene's [TFIDFSimilarity](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/similarities/TFIDFSimilarity.html), combining:

- term frequency (TF): how many times does the term `search` appear in the `title` field of this document? The more often, the higher the score
- inverse document frequency (IDF): how many times does the term `search` appear in the `title` field of all documents in the index?  The more often, the *lower* the score
- field norm: how long is the `title` field?  The longer the field, the lower the score. (Shorter fields like `title` are considered to be more important than longer fields like `body`.)
- A query normalization factor. (can be ignored)

On the other hand, a `bool` query like this:

```
"bool": {
    "should": [
        { "match": { "title": "foo" }},
        { "match": { "title": "bar" }},
        { "match": { "title": "baz" }}
    ]
}
```

would calculate the `_score` for each clause which matches, add them together then divide by the total number of clauses (and once again have the query normalization factor applied).

So it depends entirely on what queries you are using.

You can get a detailed explanation of how the `_score` was calculated by adding the `explain` parameter to your query:

```
curl localhost:9200/_search?explain -d '
{
    "query": ....
}'
```

> My question is - how can I represent each score as a ratio?

Without understanding what you want your query to do it is impossible to answer this. Depending on your use case, you could use the [`function_score` query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) to implement your own scoring algorithm.

Comment: Thanks that helps. The query is dynamically generated and can not be pre-determined. Does this mean that I'll have to run with the given score - represent it as a natural number and not a rational?

Comment: The score is kinda meaningless outside a particular query. It's only purpose is to compare one doc against another in the context of a single query, so I wouldn't use it to display a %matched value or anything like that.