# Elasticsearch scoring

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I tried this simple query:

```
{
"query":{
"range":{"ncopies":{gte:2, lte:5}}
}
}
```

and each document returned had a score of 1.

Then I tried:

```
{
"query":{
"term":{"ncopies":2}
}
}
```

and each document returned has a score of 1.52

Is there a difference in how score is calculated for "term" and "range"?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the denominator for ElasticSearch scores?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21346164/whats-the-denominator-for-elasticsearch-scores)  "The score is kinda meaningless outside a particular query. It's only purpose is to compare one doc against another in the context of a single query"

Answer (score 0):

Range query matches documents with fields that have terms within a certain range.If `ncopies` is 3,it matches ncopies>=2 &ncopies<=5,it does not analyze,just compare the value of a field.The value of  Doc1's `ncopies` is 4,Doc2's `ncopies` is 3,both match,they have the same score of 1.

Term query will use analyzer to score.

Comment: I thought 'term' didn't analyze, whereas 'match' did.